# CSS for drop down menu using asp.net sitemap not changing color on mouse over

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, visual-studio

I am trying to get my drop down menu which is made from a sitemap to change colors when there is a mouse over. Here is my code to make the menu:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
        Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="aspmenu">
        <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="test" />
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

Additionally here is the css file:

```
.level1
{

}

.level2
{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    color: White;
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background-color: #fdbe12;
    width: 6em;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
}

.level3
{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    color: White;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #fdbe12;
    width: 6.85em;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

.test
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:Fuchsia;
    color:Black;

}
```

Here is the pertinent part of the other CSS file:

```
    body
    {
       background: #EAFDB3;
       width: 100%;
    }

    #menuBar 
    { 
         text-align: left;
         width: 43.5em;
         display: block;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-top: 7.75em;
    }
```

Here is a pic:

[image]

Comment: You have no `a:hover { color...}` so where is it changing the colour?

Comment: There is no hover event defined in your css. Try adding #menuBar a:hover { /* your hover styles */ }

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake. Add an answer so I can give one of you credit.